# How can I add new constraints to existing model in Cplex Script (flow control)?

Tags: cplex, opl, flow-control

In my heuristic algorithm I solve the model multiple times with different data and after each solve I need to add some new constraints to the existing model and solve again. I want to do this in Cplex Script (flow control).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether it is an optimal way to do it (but I did not find a better one), but if your constraints have known structure, you might edit (in runtime) a set of bounds in a .dat file and let CPLEX generate constraints from it.

```
dvar float k;

{float} bounds = ...; //data.dat: bounds = {4.0};

main {
  var model = thisOplModel
  model.generate()
  cplex.solve()
  writeln(cplex.getObjValue())

  var model2 = new IloOplModel(model.modelDefinition, cplex)
  var data = model.dataElements
  data.bounds.add(3.0)
  model2.addDataSource(data)
  model2.generate()
  cplex.solve()
  writeln(cplex.getObjValue())
}

maximize k;

subject to {
  forall (b in bounds) k <= b;
}
```

The output is then

```
4
3
```

Answer (score 0):

/*
Quite often, after solving the model we need to add new variables and constraints. We can do that by writing new models but we can also do this incrementally.
Suppose we need to first know what will happen if we need to have same number of 40 seats and 30 seats buses and then allow 50 seats buses in the model.
We can write
int nbKids=300;
float costBus40=500;
float costBus30=400;
float costBus50=700;

```
    dvar int+ nbBus40;
    dvar int+ nbBus30;
    dvar int+ nbBus50;
     
    minimize
     costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+nbBus50*costBus50;
     
    subject to
    {
     ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30+nbBus50*50>=nbKids;
     
     nbBus30==nbBus40;
     nbBus50==0;
    }
    execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
    {
    writeln("The minimum cost is ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30+costBus50*nbBus50);
    writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses and ",
    nbBus50," buses 50 seats");
    }
which will give
 
    The minimum cost is 4500
    We will use 5 40 seats buses 5 30 seats buses and 0 buses 50 seats
and then if we comment
     nbBus50==0;
which means we allow 50 seats buses then we ll get
 
    The minimum cost is 4100
    We will use 3 40 seats buses 3 30 seats buses and 2 buses 50 seats
But to do that we generate 3 times the matrix which can take time.
 
We can do that in a main and be incremental. And then we do not generate new matrixes but rely on incremental changes.
The technique is simply to have spare decision variables and constraints:
*/

 

    int nbKids=300;
    float costBus40=500;
    float costBus30=400;
     
    dvar int+ nbBus40;
    dvar int+ nbBus30;
    dvar int+ emptyVar;
     
    minimize
     costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30;
     
    subject to
    {
     ctKids:40*nbBus40+nbBus30*30>=nbKids;
     
     ctEmpty:0<=0;

    }

    execute DISPLAY_After_SOLVE
    {
    writeln("The minimum cost is ",costBus40*nbBus40  +nbBus30*costBus30);
    writeln("We will use ",nbBus40," 40 seats buses and ",nbBus30," 30 seats buses ");
    writeln();
    }

    main
    {
    thisOplModel.generate();

    writeln("Basic model");

    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();

    writeln("Let us add a row : saying that nbBus40 and nbBus30 should be equal");

    thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus40,1);
    thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setCoef(thisOplModel.nbBus30,-1);
    thisOplModel.ctEmpty.setBounds(0,0);
    cplex.solve();
    thisOplModel.postProcess();

    writeln("Let us add a column : saying that nbBus50 could also be used and their cost is 700");
    cplex.setObjCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,700);
    thisOplModel.ctKids.setCoef(thisOplModel.emptyVar,50);
    cplex.solve();
    writeln("The minimum cost is ",
    thisOplModel.costBus40*thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue  +thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue*thisOplModel.costBus30
    +700*thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue);
    writeln("We will use ",thisOplModel.nbBus40.solutionValue," 40 seats buses ",thisOplModel.nbBus30.solutionValue,
    " 30 seats buses and "+thisOplModel.emptyVar.solutionValue," 50 seats buses");
    }

/*
gives
 
    Basic model
    The minimum cost is 3800
    We will use 6 40 seats buses and 2 30 seats buses
    Let us add a row : saying that nbBus40 and nbBus30 should be equal
    The minimum cost is 4500
    We will use 5 40 seats buses and 5 30 seats buses
    Let us add a column : saying that nbBus50 could also be used and their cost is 700
    The minimum cost is 4100
    We will use 3 40 seats buses 3 30 seats buses and 2 50 seats buses
Of course we get the same results. 
*/
```

from https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-decision-optimization-simple-alex-fleischer/

[Adding rows and columns incrementally](https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zooopl/blob/master/zooincremental.mod)